# Menu drawer Fragments inflates their menu even when not shown

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There must be something fundamental that I'm not fully understanding about the fragment management.

Here's the current architecture of my app:

- We have a menu activity that has been generated using the template provided in Eclipse (`MenuActivity.java`)
- Each fragments shown from the menu has two layouts. One for phone and another for tablets. These layouts only contain `FrameLayout` that are replaced with fragments using the `FragmentManager/Transaction`.
- Each fragment implements `onCreateOptionsMenu` to add their own bits of the menu.

The problem is that when I switch tabs using the drawer menu, some of the options stays in the action bar. Also, the fragment that receives the call to `onOptionsItemSelected` is always the last fragment that was selected.

Some code of `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String tag = "";

    switch(position) {
    case 0:
        tag = "tours_main_fragment";

        fragment = new ToursMainFragment();
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);

        break;

    case 1:
        tag = "motos_main_fragment";

        fragment = new MotoMainFragment();
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);

        break;

    }

    if(fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        restoreActionBar();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I gather you are using a DrawerLayout for navigation and replacing the fragment container in the main Activity layout with the appropriate fragment based on the item selected in the navigation drawer.

You might want to invalidate the options menu when the drawer is opened/closed.  As stated in the Activity API:

> **public void invalidateOptionsMenu ()**
>
> Added in API level 11
> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) >method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed.

so calling this when drawer is toggled should help recreate the menu options based on the fragment.  Example code:

```
  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
```

Comment: You're right about the fragment transactions. The problem is that the menus are not cleared when the fragment transaction happens.